# scipy stats binom cdf returns nan

Tags: python, scipy

If I understand correctly, the `cdf` for a `scipy.stats` discrete distribution should return the sum of the probabilities of the values up to the parameter given.

Thus, `scipy.stats.binom(7000000000, 0.5).cdf(6999999999)` should return something almost exactly 1, because in 7 billion trials, with a 50/50 chance, the probability of getting a success on 7 billion minus 1 of them or less is pretty much certain.  Instead, I get `np.nan`.  In fact, for any value provided to `.cdf` EXCEPT 7 billion itself (or more), I get back `np.nan`.

What is going on here?  Is there some limit to the numbers that `scipy.stats` distributions can handle that is not in the docs?

Comment: Interesting.  The underlying function is `scipy.special.bdtr`.  For `n=2**31-1`, `bdtr(n-1, n, 0.5)` returns 0.9999999999999999.  For `n=2**31`, it returns `nan`.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug in scipy.

Comment: I created an issue on github: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9454.  It might turn out to be a duplicate; there are several related issues for `scipy.stats.binom`, `scipy.special.bdtr` and `scipy.special.betainc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL; DR

Lack of floating point precision during internal calculations. Though scipy is a Python library, it's core is written on C and uses C numeric types.

---

Let me show you an example:

```
import scipy.stats

for i in range (13):
    trials = 10 ** i
    print(f"i: {i}\tprobability: {scipy.stats.binom(trials, 0.5).cdf(trials - 1)}")
```

And output is:

```
i: 0    probability: 0.5
i: 1    probability: 0.9990234375
i: 2    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 3    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 4    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 5    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 6    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 7    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 8    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 9    probability: 0.9999999999999999
i: 10   probability: nan
i: 11   probability: nan
i: 12   probability: nan
```

The reason lies in the CDF formula for binomial distribution (I can't embed images so here is link to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Inside the scipy sources we would see a refence to this implementation: http://www.netlib.org/cephes/doubldoc.html#bdtr

Deeply inside it involves division by `trials` (`incbet.c, line 375: ai = 1.0 / a;` here it's called `a`, but nwm). And if your `trials` is too large, the result of this division is so small that when we add this little number to another, not so little number, it doesn't actually change because we lack floating point precision here (only 64 bits so far). Then, after some more arithmetics, we try get logarithm from a number, but it's equal to zero as it hasn't changes when it should. And `log(0)` is not defined, which equals to `np.nan`.

Comment: I think the answer is even simpler: the number of trials is cast to a 32-bit integer by `bdtr`.  But 10**10 overflows a 32-bit integer, and `incbet` return NaN for negative `a` or `b`.  Although `incbet` does have precision issues (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5503), they don't come into play here.